# What are the physical properties of exotic ice?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, phase, solid-state-chemistry

This chart shows the phases of water that form at various combinations of pressures and temperatures.

[image: Phase diagram]

It has multiple exotic forms of ice (labeled II through XV) listed. What are the physical property differences between these exotic forms of ice, regular ice, and each other?

Comment: What properties are you interested in?

Comment: I'm really curious as to what differentiates them all. Solid, liquid,and gas all have obvious differences. How can you tell the difference between the different forms of solids?

Comment: the gist is that the different forms of ice have different crystalline structures. So all sorts of properties would have (small) differences. Density, melting point, and heat of fusion for example.